# tampermonkey how to click button without id

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

i'm trying to make a auto click button but this one has no id i already tried multiple script, but still not able to work

```js
document.querySelector('input[value="Suivant"]')[0].click();
```

```html
<div class="frm-button">
                    <input type="submit" value="Suivant" class="submitbtn">
                </div>
```

Comment: Remove the `[0]`, since `querySelector` returns a single element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** method returns a single element (the first input element with value `Suivant`) and not an array of input elements so you don't need to specify an index as seen in the following Code Snippet:

```js
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[value="Suivant"]');

inputElement.addEventListener('click', () => {

    // log "Hello" in the console when clicked
    console.log("hello"); 

})

// simulate a click on the input element with the click() method
inputElement.click();
```

```html
<div class="frm-button">
  <input type="submit" value="Suivant" class="submitbtn">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('input[value="Suivant"]').click();
```

```html
<div class="frm-button">
    <input type="submit" value="Suivant" class="submitbtn">
</div>
```

Since `querySelector` other than `querySelectorAll` return only on element instead of an array you can remove the `[0]`